# MongoDB Merge two properties from different collections into one and sort them

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm faced into the issue when I'm trying to merge the results of two MongoDB lookup's into one property, and then I want to unwind them and sort.
I have a problem with merging the results of lookup's.

Here is the actual code:

```
db.getCollection('collectionA').aggregate([
{
  $lookup:
   {
     from: 'collectionB',
     localField: "_id",
     foreignField: "collectionAKey",
     as: "collectionBInfo"
   }
},
{
  $lookup:
   {
     from: 'collectionC',
     localField: "_id",
     foreignField: "collectionAKey",
     as: "collectionCInfo"
   }
},
/// then I just want to create one property from both of lookup's, unwind them and sort by the timestamp
{
  $unwind: "$mergedCollectionsAandB"
},
{
  $sort: {
      "mergedCollectionsAandB.timestamp": -1
  }      
}
])
```

Here is a models of collections:

```
CollectionA
_id
name

CollectionB
_id
timestamp
collectionAKey

CollectionC
_id
timestamp
collectionAKey
```

I assume that it's possible by using $mergeObjects MongoDB operator, but I'm stuck a little bit how to do it in a right way. Is that possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: soo it looks like I should use $concatArrays for that

Answer (score 1):

So the final version of my query looks like that, it's what I was looking for:

```
db.getCollection('collectionA').aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
       {
         from: 'collectionB',
         localField: "_id",
         foreignField: "collectionAKey",
         as: "collectionBInfo"
       }
    },
    {
      $lookup:
       {
         from: 'collectionC',
         localField: "_id",
         foreignField: "collectionAKey",
         as: "collectionCInfo"
       }
    },
    {
      $project: {  
        "mergedCollectionsAandB": { $concatArrays: ["$collectionBInfo", "$collectionCInfo"] }
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$mergedCollectionsAandB"
    },
    {
      $sort: {
          "mergedCollectionsAandB.timestamp": -1
      }      
    }
])
```